# delta live table expectations syntax looks different

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I was looking at a code and saw that the expect_all is coded as below

```
dlt.expect_all(dict_expectations)(dlt_quarantine_view)
```

My understanding of the syntax was that it takes a dictionary of expectations and executes that, i am not able ti understand why the second argument in brackets is there.

Comment: where do you see it? official documentation still only lists single argument (dictionary)

Comment: Rajb - where have you seen such syntax?

Comment: One of my colleague shared this with me, but I did not have the environment to run it . So could not figure out how it works